# Unable to launch a GKE (Google Container Engine) cluster with a custom network

Tags: networking, google-compute-engine, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm trying to launch a GKE cluster with a "custom" type network, vs. a "auto" type network.

I use the following command to launch my cluster:

```
$ gcloud container clusters create --cluster-ipv4-cidr=10.0.0.0/14 --network=ttest --subnetwork=ttest --num-nodes=1 jt
```

I get the following error:

```
Creating cluster jt...done.
ERROR: (gcloud.container.clusters.create) Operation [<Operation
 name: u'operation-1467037655793-e319dc5e'
 operationType: OperationTypeValueValuesEnum(CREATE_CLUSTER, 1)
 selfLink: u'https://container.googleapis.com/v1/projects/TRUNCATED/zones/us-east1-b/operations/operation-1467037655793-e319dc5e'
 status: StatusValueValuesEnum(DONE, 3)
 statusMessage: u'Requested CIDR 10.0.0.0/14 is not available in network "ttest".'
 targetLink: u'https://container.googleapis.com/v1/projects/TRUNCATED/zones/us-east1-b/clusters/jt'
 zone: u'us-east1-b'>] finished with error: Requested CIDR 10.0.0.0/14 is not available in network "ttest".
```

It seems to want a network or subnetwork with a `/14` address range, so the command *should* ideally work, but it doesn't.

Which is very odd, because here is what my networks look like:

The ttest network:

```
$ gcloud compute networks describe ttest

autoCreateSubnetworks: false
creationTimestamp: '2016-06-27T07:25:03.691-07:00'
id: '5404409453117999568'
kind: compute#network
name: ttest
selfLink: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/myproject/global/networks/ttest
subnetworks:
- https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/myproject/regions/us-east1/subnetworks/ttest
x_gcloud_mode: custom
```

The ttest subnetwork:

```
$ gcloud compute networks subnets describe ttest

creationTimestamp: '2016-06-27T07:25:21.649-07:00'
gatewayAddress: 10.0.0.1
id: '6237639993374575038'
ipCidrRange: 10.0.0.0/14
kind: compute#subnetwork
name: ttest
network: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/myproject/global/networks/ttest
region: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/myproject/regions/us-east1
selfLink: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/myproject/regions/us-east1/subnetworks/ttest
```

I've tried the same thing with a manually created legacy network with `--range=10.0.0.0/8` and then tried creating a cluster in that network, that doesn't seem to work either.

It would seem the /14 rule is hardcoded into the GKE configs somewhere, but I don't really know what it wants in the custom network to launch the containers.

The GKE container launch command works with any network where the mode/type is ["auto".](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networking#creating_a_new_network_with_auto-created_subnetwork_ranges)

I pored over whatever documentation seemed relevant to me, but without much luck. The only that sticks out the following snippet from [this page](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/subnetworks#restrictions):

> The following restrictions exist when using subnetworks with other
>   products:
>
> - Google Managed VMs: Supported only on auto subnetwork networks. Cannot be deployed in a custom subnet networks.

Does GKE use Managed VMs under the hood? Is that what's causing the problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

GKE does support custom subnet networks. The problem you're having is that GKE enforces that the `cluster-ipv4-cidr` range is disjoint from all subnetworks in which VMs may have their IPs allocated from, because that would lead to ambiguity in where packets should be routed on the internal network.

`cluster-ipv4-cidr` determines which CIDR ranges should be used for the containers in the cluster, while the subnet used determines which IP addresses are used for all VMs created in that network.

To fix the problem, simply stop specifying the `--cluster-ipv4-cidr` flag in your gcloud command. GKE will then pick a safe `cluster-ipv4-cidr` range for you.

Comment: Hi Alex, I tried this and it works with the fresh network I created (as shown above), but it doesn't work with another network I have, I get the same error (when I don't specify the CIDR), any idea what else might be going wrong?

Comment: It's possible that the other network does not have enough available space to allocate a /14. This could be because of subnetworks filling up the 10.0.0.0/8 space, or from advanced routes using the whole space. What is the exact error message you see?

Comment: @CJCullen The exact error message I saw was `The network "mynetwork" does not have available private IP space in 10.0.0.0/8 to reserve a /14 block for this cluster`.

I figured out the answer late last night, the VPN for this network was configured with `Remote IP Network Ranges` as `0.0.0.0/0` at one point and then with `10.0.0.0/8` at another, GKE probably looks at this (I don't know how) and figures out it doesn't have space of it's own and complains. Surprisingly though, I can figure up compute engine instances just fine.

Comment: Marking this as the accepted solution because Alex's answer is correct for the question I asked.

Comment: Yeah, GKE inspects the existing routes and assumes that they are being used for something important, and avoids allocating the cluster CIDR there. Compute Engine instances have already "claimed" whatever the IP Range of the network is, so they don't need to tiptoe around things that came later.

Comment: @CJCullen Wait, so you're saying there's no way to start GKE instances in a VPN then? Because VPN setup requires adding a route to tell the tunnel which IPs to accept/route. Setting up a VPN for the GKE subnet is required because packets sent to the `10.0.0.0/8` subnet are not masqueraded with the underlying host machine's IP, so packets don't go through to the VPN.

Comment: What CIDR range are you expecting to route over the VPN tunnel? It shouldn't conflict with the range that GKE uses for its Pods. If it did, pods may not be able to communicate with one another. Am I misunderstanding?